# Device Memory allocation is different in nsight Eclipse and netbeans

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, cuda, nsight

Below is the written code I am executing in `nsight eclipse` and `Netbeans`. I am getting different memory allocation size. I am not able to understand why it is happening. If anyone has any clue please help.

```
int main()
{
    cuComplex *a,*b;
    float *c;
    double mfree,mtotal;
    size_t mem1,mem2;
    int Size = 8192;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a,sizeof(cuComplex)*Size*Size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&b,sizeof(cuComplex)*Size*Size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&c,sizeof(float)*Size*Size);

    cudaMemGetInfo(&mem1,&mem2);
    mfree = (double)mem1/1024*1024;
    mtotal = (double)mem2/1024*1024;

    printf("Total memory = %f and Free Memory = %f",mtotal,mfree);
}
```

Below is the output in both platforms

Output in Nsight Eclipse

```
Total memory = 2001.8125 and Free Memory = 105.625
```

Output in Netbeans

```
Total memory = 2001.8125 and Free Memory = 572.125
```

Comment: What are the status before/without cudaMallocs? Currently the memory allocation size is not shown.

Comment: @DanM. I checked the memory before the allocation its seems nsight is reserving around 615MB initilally while Netbeans only reserves 200MB ... How i can manage the pre allocation

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The memory is shared among all programs using GPU. Similar to RAM. You can only reduce the usage by closing not needed programs.
It may also be possible, depending on your setup, to run entirely from integrated GPU and use nvidia GPU solely as an accelerator, but how to do that is another question entirely.

Comment: To add to what Dan says, this also happens if you open Youtube in chrome before running the seconds experiment, if you are using the GPU for graphics too (common setup). Other software uses the GPU.

Comment: @AnderBiguri that i am able to understand but i am opening the software one by one at a time either Netbeans or nsingh while there is no other application is running .Even then nsight takes more GPu memory in that case i think nsight only reserving this amount of GPu memory to run it self, which should not happen it's taking almost 30% of my Device memory :(

Comment: @VikasSingh Everything hints that yes, its reserving that amount for itself. I dont have it at hand right now, later I might be able to check how much it takes in my machine.